# Don't close stdin after initial value was processed in Java

Tags: java, console, java.util.scanner, stdin

I am making simple console app. My main loop looks like this.

```java
var s = new Scanner(System.in);
while (appShouldRun) {
    var action = s.nextLine();
    // proccess action
}
```

It works fine when I run app with empty stdin.

```sh
java -jar app.jar
```

But I want to have some prepared scenarios in file. Run them and then wait for next user input.

Expected behaviour:

```sh
java -jar app.jar < scenario.txt

output of commands from file

| <- cursor, waiting for user input
```

```
// scenario.txt

cmd1
cmd2
cmd3
.
.
.
```

Problem is that when I run program with something od std in, it process commands correctly, but then it throws

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
```

I think it's becouse stdin is closed after all lines from file is processed.
Am I wrong?
How to fix the code to get expected behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: `while (appShouldRun)` -> `while (appShouldRun && s.hasNextLine())`

Comment: @Michael It doesn't solve my problem, becouse it stops the program and don't wait for additional user input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you redirect standard input with `<`, it is connected to the input file, and *not connected at all* to the console.

If you want your program to receive input on the console, then you can't redirect stdin.  You should take the filename as a command-line argument instead.  Open it, read it, close it, and then process stdin.

OR, if you really want to, and you're on a unix/linux/macOS system, you can run it like this, using the `cat` command to concatenate standard input to something else:

```
cat scenario.txt - | java -jar app.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried do change as little code as possible. This reads the whole file like you wanted and ends without Exception

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean appShouldRun = true;
        while (appShouldRun) {
            String action = s.nextLine();
            System.out.println("got: " + action);
            appShouldRun = s.hasNext();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tahnks for your answer, but this is similar to Michaels comment. Sure, it ends without Exception, but then it does not wait for next user input.